# Multi threading with shared variable

Tags: python, multithreading

I've got this program:

```
def optimal(t0, tf, frequences, delay, ratio = 0):

    First = True              
    for s in delay:
        delay = 0                           
        timelines = list()

        for i in range(len(frequences)):
            timelines.append(time_builder(frequences[i], t0+delay, tf))
            delay += s

        It takes in input an initial time t0, a final time tf, a list of 5 frequencies, and this `
```

If the value `s` meets the requirements, `i.e valid = True` and `optim_param_1 < optimal[3]`, then optimal is replaced with `optimal = (s, _overlap, __trio_overlap, optim_param_1)`.

The problem is that there are many possibilities for s to be tested and that the computation within is quite long. I would like to use several threads to speed up the process. I've never actually done it and I've been read there are limitations and algorithm design choices to make to avoid false results.

First question, is it possible to modify this algorithm into a multithread one?
Second question, is `from threading import Thread` the right solution?
Third question, since optimal is shared between threads (comparison to find out if the solution is better than the previous best one), should I create one optimal per thread and then compare which one of the optimal is the best, or is there another way?

Thanks for the tips, I really don't know where to start with multithreading....

EDIT: Some s value computation might be fast, and some quite long. There is not 2 with the same duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently do not have time to create an extended answer, but still would like to give you some hints.

1. Since your computations do not directly depend on each other, it is possible to parallelize the problem.
2. Using `threading.Thread` is not the correct solution, since it runs all threads in the same process. Use `multiprocessing.Process` instead (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html). The interface is similar to that of `threading.Thread`.
3. There are at least two solutions I can imagine:

   - Use one `optimal` variable per process to store the optimum values for that process. Your current program stops when `optim_param_1 < 0.3` is satisfied. So you could have a shared `multiprocessing.Event` that is set when one process finds a solution with `optim_param_1 < 0.3`. All other threads can then stop themselves when the event is set.
   - Share a `multiprocessing.Queue` between the worker processes and the main process. Whenever a worker process calculated a new result, put it in the queue. The main process should check for new results in the queue in a loop and compare the results to its `optimal` variable. When it found a solution that satisfies `optim_param_1 < 0.3` it can stop all worker processes.

Personally I would choose the second solution. It separates the calculation of the results (in the worker process) from the valuation of the results (in the main process).
You can easily scale and manage the whole thing using the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` class.

The documentation on the multiprocessing module has some nice examples: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#examples

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna look into it as soon as I can. I understand the 2 solutions, although I have no idea of how implementing a loop checking when a variable is updated (the queue).

Comment: If you have time, could you have a look to the modification I brought ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927506/multiprocessing-with-shared-queue