# Multiprocessing with shared queue and end criteria

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've got this original function that I want to switch to multiprocess:

```
def optimal(t0, tf, frequences, delay, ratio = 0):

    First = True                            # First        
    for s in delay:
        delay = 0                           # delay between signals,
        timelines = list()

        for i in range(len(frequences)):
            timelines.append(time_builder(frequences[i], t0+delay, tf))
            delay += s

       trio_overlap = trio_combination(timelines, ratio)

        valid = True
        for items in trio_overlap.values():
            if len(list(set(items))) == len(items):
                continue
            else:
                valid = False

        if not valid:
            continue

        overlap = duo_combination(timelines)

    optimal = ... depending of conditions        
    return optimal
```

If `valid = True` after the test, it will compute an optimization parameter called `optim_param` and try to minimize it. If it gets under a certain threshold, `optim_param < 0.3`, I break out of the loop and take this value as my answer.

My problem is that as I develop my model, the complexity is starting to rise, and single thread computation takes too long. I would like to process the computation in parallel. Since each process will have to compare the result obtained with an s value to the current optimal, I tried to implement a Queue.

It's my first time doing multiprocessing, and even if I think I'm on the right track, I kinda feel like my code is messy and incomplete. Could I get some help?

Thanks :D

Comment: Aside from making my computer crash, this solution has little effect :/

Comment: You showed the sample input on`shift` and `frequencies`. Could you show the sample input of `t0` and `tf`? Also, could you revise the `shift` with less steps? Say, `1000` or `10000` runs in parallel to ease the initial testing?

Comment: t0 and tf are the initial and final time that are used to compute the timelines (which is a list of instant, let's say [0, 50, 100, 150] for a 20 Hz signal). Let's say `t0 = 0` and `tf = 200`. For shift of course we can take `np.arange(0, 2, 0.1)` to start with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of manually creating a process for each case, consider using `Pool.imap_unordered`.  The trick is how to cleanly shut down when a passable result is obtained: you can implement this by passing a generator that exits early in case a flag is set that it checks every cycle.  The main program reads from the iterator, maintains the best result seen, and sets the flag when it is good enough.  The final trick is to slow down the (internal) thread reading from the generator to prevent a large backlog of scheduled tasks that must be waited on (or, uncleanly, killed) after the good result is obtained.  Given the number of processes in the pool, that pacing can be achieved with a semaphore.

Here's an example (with trivial analysis) to demonstrate:

```
import multiprocessing,threading,os

def interrupted(data,sem,interrupt):
  for x in data:
    yield x
    sem.acquire()
    if interrupt: break

def analyze(x): return x**2

np=os.cpu_count()
pool=multiprocessing.Pool(np)
sem=threading.Semaphore(np-1)
token=[]                        # mutable

vals=pool.imap_unordered(analyze,interrupted(range(-10,10),sem,token))
pool.close()                    # optional: to let processes exit faster

best=None
for res in vals:
  if best is None or res<best:
    best=res
    if best<5: token.append(None) # make it truthy
  sem.release()
pool.join()

print(best)
```

There are of course other ways to share the semaphore and interrupt flag with the generator; this way uses an ugly data type but has the virtue of using no global variables (or even closures).

Comment: I kinda get the idea. I'll look into it, however, this is my first time using multiprocessing, and even if I'm not a beginner in python, I'm far from being fluent.

Comment: I get the idea behind it, but I can't manage to produce a working code on my own... Despite the many trials and pc crash x')

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look tommorow.